# Is there a way for a RACSignal to keep receiving `next`s after an error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

I'm trying to listen for both location updates and errors (through `CLLocationManagerDelegate`), and support the ability to track errors but filter them out of the final signal and keep it alive.

When I subscribe to the location signal (via ReactiveCocoaPlayground's [`-[LocationManager currentLocationSignal]`](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/reactive-cocoa-playground/blob/master/src/reactive-cocoa-playground/LocationManager/LocationManager.m)), any errors received will end the signal.

I've tried `-catch:` and `-catchTo:` but those just catch one error and then end the signal.

I've tried returning a brand new instance of that signal inside `-catch:`, but then the error on THAT signal is uncaught (which causes a crash in a `RAC()` binding later on).

I've tried a recursive approach to that catch as well, which caused a stack overflow (maybe I just made a mistake though).

Is there a way to receive `next`s after errors occur?

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [`retry`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L541) is for?

Comment: Well would you look at that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`-[RACSignal retry]`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L541):

```
/// Resubscribes to the receiving signal if an error occurs.
- (RACSignal *)retry;
```